# Laravel order by nested relationship using dot notation

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to order my top level model called `Domain` by my nested relationship called `Certificate`.

A user can choose to order by the domain columns, or, by the certificate.

I'm working in Laravel 9 and PHP 8.1, and this is my attempt so far:

```php
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'perPage' => 'nullable|integer|in:10,25,50,100,250',
        'sort' => 'nullable|string|in:added,registered,expiry,domain,expiry_ssl',
        'search' => 'nullable|string|max:256',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'It looks like you missed something',
            'errors' => $validator->errors(),
        ], 400);
    }

    // search filter
    $search = $request->input('search') ?? '';
    $search = strtolower($search);

    // results per page
    $perPage = $request->input('perPage') ?? 10;

    // sort by filter
    $sort = $request->input('sort') ?? ['created_at', 'desc'];
    if ($sort == 'added') {
        $sort = ['created_at', 'desc'];
    }
    if ($sort == 'registered') {
        $sort = ['created_on', 'desc'];
    }
    if ($sort == 'expiry') {
        $sort = ['expires_on', 'asc'];
    }
    if ($sort == 'domain') {
        $sort = ['domain', 'asc'];
    }
    if ($sort == 'expiry_ssl') {
        $sort = ['certificate.expires_on', 'asc'];
    }

    try {
        $domains = Domain::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                    ->where(function ($sql) use ($search) {
                        $sql->orWhere('domain', 'like', "$search%")
                          ->orWhere('status', 'like', "$search%")
                          ->orWhere('registrar', 'like', "$search%");
                    })
                    ->with('certificate')
                    ->orderBy($sort[0] ?? 'expires_on', $sort[1] ?? 'desc')
                    ->paginate((int) $perPage);

    } catch (\Exception $err) { }

}
```

This throws an error, what could I be missing? Trying to order `certificate.expires_on`

Comment: What error?
I am not an expert of Laravel / Eloquent, but I think you should make a ->join() with the 'certificate' table ->on() the corrct id field, not a ->with('certificate').
The with instruction does a secon query and loads the resource but it does not make the secondary table available to the main query so you can't use certificate.expires_on

Comment: When selecting a column of a relational table, you need to specify the table name, follow by a dot notation and the column name. If your certificate table goes by certificates, you would do it like: `->orderBy('certificates.expires_on')`

Answer (score 0):

Use a join (put the correct fields that link the certificate resource to the main table and table names):

```
$domains = Domain::where('user_id', Auth::id())
->join('certificate', 'certificate.certificate_id', '=', 'domain.certificate_id')
```